# How do I get DIV to disappear when another DIV is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html

I've got the following code that works great!  When I click Link 1, the DIV content appears.  When I click it again, it disappears.  If I click Link 1 again, the DIV content appears again.  If I click Link 2 this time, the content appears along with Link 1 content.  I want Link 1 to disappear if another DIV link is clicked.  I don't want to have to turn that content off before turning another one on.  How do I make a DIV disappear after another one is clicked?

Javascript:

```
function show(ele)    {      
    var srcElement = document.getElementById(ele);      
    if(srcElement != null)      {         
      if(srcElement.style.display == "block")         {      
        srcElement.style.display= 'none';       
      }         
      else         { 
        srcElement.style.display='block';         
      }      
    }   
    return false;
  }
```

DIV:

```
<a href="#" onclick="show('link1')">FIRST LINK</a> 
<a href="#" onclick="show('link2')">SECOND LINK</a>

<div id="link1" style="display:none">
   <p>Link 1 Content Displayed</p>
</div>

<div id="link2" style="display:none">
   <p>Link 2 Content Displayed</p>
</div>
```

I don't want to change the way I'm doing this, I feel like there's a simple solution, I just can't figure it out!  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: save the id of what is clicked. Test at the top of the function, if the same link, toggle, if not, hide saved and toggle

Comment: Give all the DIVs that you want to hide the same class, and use getElementsByClassName to loop over them and hide them before making the current one appear.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention that javascript is foreign to me.  I grabbed this code from elsewhere.  I'm not even sure I know how to do what you said.

Comment: Well, we're not here to teach you how to program. If you need to use Javascript, get a book on it.

Comment: I didn't ask for your demeaning comments.  I'd simply like someone to give me an example by showing me some script.  There's nothing wrong with asking others for help.  That's why this site is here.

Comment: Barmar, that's just not constructive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another, better answer would be to use jQuery, because it lets you write better javascript without having to worry about whether IE is going to break.

include this tag in the head:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Javascript:

```
function show( elem )
{
    $('.dynamic_link').hide();
    $('#'+elem).show();
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" onclick="show('link1')">FIRST LINK</a> 
<a href="#" onclick="show('link2')">SECOND LINK</a>

<div id="link1" class="dynamic_link" style="display:none">
   <p>Link 1 Content Displayed</p>
</div>

<div id="link2" class="dynamic_link" style="display:none">
   <p>Link 2 Content Displayed</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript (modified):

```
 function show(ele)    {      
    var links = ['link1','link2'];
    var srcElement = document.getElementById(ele);      
    var doShow = true;
    if(srcElement != null && srcElement.style.display == "block")
        doShow = false;
    for( var i = 0; i < links.length; ++i )    {
        var otherElement = document.getElementById(links[i]);      
        if( otherElement != null )
            otherElement.style.display = 'none';
    }
    if( doShow )
        srcElement.style.display='block';         
    return false;
  }
```

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/vDKmA/

Comment: Thank you T.W.R. Cole.  Unfortunately when I tried this out, I clicked Link 1 and then Link 2 and they both stayed visible and neither one will go away whether I click another link or the same link.

Comment: It does.  I apologize.  I must have done something wrong the first time I tried it out.  This helps tremendously.  Thank you.